# rake db:schema:load loads schema.rb multiple times?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

After upgrading from Rails 3 to Rails 4 the `db:schema:load` task is failing.  I did some digging into it and found that after the upgrade when I run `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` the `db/schema.rb` file is being loaded twice.  The first time it runs fine; then the second time through it fails due to a `create_table force: true` fails due to there being a dependency constraint on the table.

I've stripped out every additional rake task and enhance to try and rule out any of my code, but still this loads the schema.rb twice.  It is always exactly twice as I am able to run it successfully on SQLite and see the same behavior there, but it runs to completion due to SQLite not enforcing the table constraints.

Comment: I'm seeing this in Rails 5, but only in the development environment. RAILS_ENV=test works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing it twice because in `development` Rails runs db tasks for `test` and `development` in the same run.

Please see the [ActiveRecord::Tasks::Databasetasks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb) file for details, especially methods `#load_schema_current` (this one because you were referring to it) and `#each_current_configuration`

Comment: If this is all it is, then why the error?

Answer (score 0):

You might check to be sure your Rakefile isn't loading tasks twice. When Rake registers a task with the same name as an existing task, it will run both in sequence rather than replace the old definition with the new one.